# How can auto add .html in last url with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i'm using Codeigniter for my website. I had add url_suffix in config

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

Normal i create $href with  same below code

```
 echo "<li><a href='".base_url()."products.html' class=\"current\">Products</a></li>";
```

I must add .html in last. How can i auto add .html in url but i don't need fill it in last

Answer (score 0):

You should use **site_url()**

Your href should look like this `site_url('controller/method');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use site_url() function for auto generate of URL in codeigniter

**Use this:**

```
echo "<li><a href='".site_url('products')."' class=\"current\">Products</a></li>";
```

**Instead:**

```
echo "<li><a href='".base_url()."products.html' class=\"current\">Products</a></li>";
```